# Old book about mages who derive their power from crystals on their staffs and channel it in partnership with an owl familiar

Tags: story-identification, books

I took out a series of books in the late 90's that I believe were done by TOR. I am trying to track down the title of the series.

The story is essentially about mages who derive their power from crystals on their staffs and channel it in partnership with an owl familiar. When a mage died they basically turned into a sort of ghost that could still be talked to but was otherwise harmless until one of the ghost mages figured out how to possess one of the trainee ones. Can't remember why/how.

I vaguely remember there being a cross over of cultures where some mages discover a city that is essentially a giant tower. The books talked about all the pollution in the air above the tower and the people who lived there had highly advanced technology that the mages had never seen before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[Lon Tobyn Chronicles](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?18311)* by David B. Coe

From the [Kirkus review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/david-b-coe/the-children-of-amarid/) of *Children of Amarid*:

> First of a sword-and-sorcery series in which, a thousand years ago,
> Amarid and Theron founded a magical order whose new members become
> mages by acquiring bird familiars (necessary for the magic to work),
> staffs, and ceryll crystals, which focus and project the magic. Now,
> someone impersonating a mage is spreading death and destruction across
> Tobyn-Ser, so confidence in the real Children of Amarid collapses. The
> mage Baden, accepting his nephew Jaryd as apprentice, heads for a big
> meeting of the Children, hoping to discuss the matter and determine
> who's behind it. But the mages are argumentative and complacent,
> agreeing on little, so Baden arranges a dangerous trek to consult
> Theron's huffy ghost (a task no one has survived). Afterward, the
> powerful mage Sartol, a traitor secretly in league with invaders using
> advanced technology to counterfeit magic powers, claims that Baden's
> the traitor and that Jaryd was killed by Theron's ghost!

Comment: You are a wonderful human being. Thank you :)